# TRANSACTION_REFUSED when trying to refund a sale through paypal's REST API (php)

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am trying to refund a sale using the REST API and sandbox accounts. I do the following:

```
$payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get("PAY-97Y13156VA872894FKO7Kxxx", $apiContext);
$resources = $payment->transactions[0]->getRelatedResources();
$saleId = $resources[0]->getSale()->getId();
$amt = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amt->setCurrency('EUR')->setTotal('6.00');
$refund = new \PayPal\Api\Refund();
$refund->setAmount($amt);

$sale = new \PayPal\Api\Sale();
$sale->setId($saleId);
try {
    $sale->refund($refund, $apiContext);
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
    exit;
}
```

This gives the following error:

> {"name":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","message":"The request was
>   refused.{0}","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#TRANSACTION_REFUSED","debug_id":"2334757d51bcd"}

The documentation isn't helpful as to what this error could be attributed to. The original transaction's amount was 16 EUR. Is there any way to debug this further or any hints as to what might be wrong?

Comment: Is that a fake payment id (if not I'd change it)?

Comment: It's not, but it's a sandbox transaction so I thought it wouldn't mind. Anyway I've edited it to exlude some characters.

Comment: I have the same problem have you find a way to refund using paypal rest api?

Comment: @GhadaSalem not as far as I remember...

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem right now. Have tried to refund the full 16 EUR? In my case it is the only way I can refund a "PayPal sale transaction". I really wonder why it's not possible to partially refund the sale transaction in the given case. The documentation says here like 10 possible reason why the transaction ended being refused, but not exactly why.

**EDIT**:
So after some digging, I think the problem (in my case) resides in the configuration of my 'facilitator' account.

Assuming you are working with the sandbox, goto: [Dashboard] and click on [Accounts] (which is listed under the headline "Sandbox"). Click the arrow left to the (facilitator) account and click profile to view the settings of the account.Make sure you have the same setting s as in the picture below

[image: Account settings]

I had for example set the "Payment review" option to "ON" and I was'nt therefore able to make partial refund on a sale.

**For debugging purpose**:

Look up for your sale object ([PayPal Sale Object](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#sale-object)) to see it's `eligibility`
Look in your sale object for the attributes `protection_eligibility` and `protection_eligibility_type`

I hope this helps

G.

Me

Answer (score 0):

One thing that often causes problems is that the buyer & seller accounts must be different. In sandbox, that means creating two test accounts: The '-facilitator' account corresponds to the client credentials. You must create another representing a fake consumer.

Comment: I am testing using 2 different test accounts. Moreover, the buying process works perfectly, it's the refund that I can't make it work